# How to get street address from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing a program that gets the complete location from google maps, I managed to get latitude and longitude, but when it comes to address, I did everything as mentioned in different websites but I get an empty List.

Here is the code :

This is the function that saves the address in a list

```
public List<Address> getAddress() {
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        double latitude, longitude;
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
        longitude =  Double.parseDouble(lng);
        System.out.println(latitude + " / " + longitude);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude ,
                    longitude, 2);
            return addresses;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "latitude and longitude are null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the function that calls it :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lng = location.getLongitude() + "";
    lat = location.getLatitude() + "";

    try
    {
        getAddress();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Can't Call getAddress()");
    }

    gotoLocation(location);

}
```

This is the given error each time the onLocationChanged() is called

> 06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at com.MOS.fastfood.MapActivity.getAddress(MapActivity.java:559)
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at com.MOS.fastfood.MapActivity.onLocationChanged(MapActivity.java:522)
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpe$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>   06-16 12:06:23.595: W/System.err(28123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   06-16 12:06:23.600: W/System.err(28123):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is the manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MOS.fastfood"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<!-- added permission manually to reveice MAP -->
<permission
    android:name="com.MOS.fastfood.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<!-- permissions to access internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<!-- important permissions to fetch map from google -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.MOS.fastfood.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- only devices that support version 2.0 of openGL can download, for graphics -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- two permissions used to determine the current location using network towers and gps -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- ADDING THE DEBUGGING KEY -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***" />

    <!-- THIS META DATA ALLOWS "ISGOOGLEPLAYSERVICES ENABLED" TO FUNCTION WITHOUT CRASH -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AddRestaurantActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_restaurant" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RestaurantInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rate" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Loader"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_loader" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: it is posted, the first block of code

Comment: You have internet on this device?

Comment: sure, the map works perfectly, and the location works great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 Geocoder geocoder;
 List<Address> addresses;
 geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1     represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
 String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()

String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

Comment: I did, but yet it gives me the same problem, empty list.

Comment: lng = location.getLongitude() + "";
    lat = location.getLatitude() + ""; code remove +"" change  lng = location.getLongitude() ; and  lat = location.getLatitude() ;

Comment: same problem, the lng and lat are actually string, and i used the +"" to convert them to string and it works, but when i use latitude and longitude inside the geocoder.getFromLocation(), i use another variables which are doubles.